# how do I display the most recent external command's output?

Tags: neovim

Using Neovim, you can execute external commands via:

`:!<external command>`

This will display an alert/message with the result of the command.

How can I access that result of an external command later?
e.g.:
`:!echo "Where is my file?"` I would expect to have some type of log buffer (or something similar), with "Where is my file?" displayed, somewhere.

Upon searching, I've seen that `g<` or `:messages` should display this information, but that does not seem to be the case.

What am I missing? Surely there is a built-in method to retrieve the most recent alert?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693959/how-to-show-the-output-from-the-last-shell-command-run-in-vim-e-g-from-ec even though the accepted answer doesn't work

Comment: @AndyRay NeoVim != Vim, in this case. There is not functional parity between what is written in that thread and this one.